# Copying JSON data in to array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to get the data from a JSON file and copy the key and value pair to the array.
For example:

```
jsondata = {
    'Name': {'text': {'name': 'John'}},
    'Age': {'number': {'age': '22'}}
}
```

in to

```
array=[["Name","text","name","John"]
       ["Age","number","age","22"]]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Looking into the `lodash` package. I'm pretty sure there's a function for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vanilla js it could be something like this:

```js
data = {
    'Name': {'text': {'name': 'John'}},
    'Age': {'number': {'age': '22'}}
}

function linearize(obj) {
    if (typeof obj !== 'object')
        return [obj];
    var res = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        for (var a of linearize(obj[key])) {
            res.push([key].concat(a))
        }
    }
    return res;
}

r = linearize(data)
console.log(r)
```

Comment: This approach assume the nesting is always 2 steps deep, my code assume there is only ever one child per nested object, @javier's code assume you have access to `.map` and `arrow functions`, the moral of the story is `lodash` has probably solved this kind of problem already :)

Comment: @JasonSperske: `this approach assume the nesting is always 2 steps deep` - why?

Comment: Totally missed the recursive call in your inner for-loop, my bad.  Apparently we were both working on the same approach but yours is more flexible

Answer (score 2):

Without using external libraries, you can try:

```
function concatify (json) {
    return typeof json == "string" ? json : Object.keys(json).reduce((x,y) => x.concat(y).concat(concatify(json[y])), []);
}

Object.keys(jsondata).map(k => [k].concat(concatify(jsondata[k])));
```

or

```
Object.keys(json).map(k => [k].concat(JSON.stringify(json[k]).replace(/["\{\}]/g,'').split(':')))
```